# How do I fix the attribute error in my code?

Tags: python

I've been working on a hangman simulator for a school assessment but I can't seem to figure out why this piece of code returns ,

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isalhpa'

I'm not sure if I'm using `isalpha` correctly. Is anyone able to help me out?

Heres my code:

```
alpha = False
while alpha == False:
    ## Let the user guess a letter
    letterGuess = input("Guess a letter: ")
    ## If it's longer or shorter than 1 then re-guess
    if len(letterGuess) == 1:
        alpha = letterGuess.isalhpa()
    else:
        print("Only guess one letter at a time")
```

I want this to make `alpha` true when the length of the letter guess is 1 and when it's an alphabetical character

Comment: You may have just misspelled `isalhpa()`, try `letterGuess.isalpha()` instead (voting to close as typo).

Comment: letterGuess is an input, which gets stored as a `str`. You can't call `isalhpa()` on a string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
alpha = False
while alpha == False:
## Let the user guess a letter
letterGuess = input("Guess a letter: ")
## If it's longer or shorter than 1 then re-guess
if len(letterGuess) and letterGuess.isalpha()== 1:
    alpha = True
else:
    print("Only guess one letter at a time")
```

Note: Never put your school homework here.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot! Did exactly what I needed it to

Answer (score -1):

```py
alpha = False
while alpha == False:

    letterGuess = input("Guess a letter: ")

    if len(letterGuess) == 1:
        alpha = True
    else:
        print("Only guess one letter at a time")
```

Now if the length of the input is 1, then it breaks out of the loop and does what you need it to do with alpha.